# Weird graphical glitch Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, xubuntu, screen-corruption

My friend's machine goes on the fritz occasionally. I was able to capture it over remote desktop viewing. [Here's an imgur album.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF5QM.jpg)

He is runnign Xubuntu 14.04, and using two screens of identical make and model

Right hand screen looked like this:
[image: right-hand screen]

Left hand screen looked like this:
[image: left-hand screen]

Rebooting fixes it, but that's annoying.

Any idea what it is and how to fix it?